# How to add TypeScript definition files to source control?

Tags: git, typescript, asp.net-core, npm, libman

I have simple asp.net core web application, where I have installed javascript libraries using libman.

I want to use typescript, so I have installed typescript definition files for the libraries using npm, e.g:

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/bootstrap --save-dev
```

I would like to add the .d.ts files to source control, so that other developers does not have to rely on NPM - it is the purpose of libman, isn't it?

/node_modules folder is ignored in .gitignore by default.

How do I include the typescript definition files?

Comment: Remove `node_modules` from `.gitignore`?

Comment: the problem is that node_modules contains a lot of garbage, readme files, json files, javascript files... why the question was downvoted, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have installed javascript libraries using `LibMan`, you could simply reuse the `LibMan` to install the definitions too :

```
libman install @types/jquery -p unpkg
libman install @types/bootstrap -p unpkg
```

The default path will be `libs/@types`：

```
lib/
    @types/
        bootstrap/
            index.d.ts
            ...
        jquery/
            index.d.ts
            ...
```

I create a `tsconfig.json` and configure path mapping to load modules as below :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "jquery": ["lib/@types/jquery"] ,
            "bootstrap":["lib/@types/bootstrap"]
        }
      }
}
```

Now we can benefit from the typescript:

[image]

**[Update]**

For ASPNET-CORE project, the default path will be :`wwwroot/lib/@types`, if we have our `tsconfig.json` under the project directory (next to the `*.csproj` project file ), we need change the path to :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "jquery": ["wwwroot/lib/@types/jquery"] ,
            "bootstrap":["wwwroot/lib/@types/bootstrap"]
        }
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, however I wasn't able to get it working with global variables, type $ or jQuery...

Comment: @Liero Did you import jquery by `import $ from "jquery"` ?  the "jquery" module doesn't not export a `$`, so we need import everything as `$` or `jQuery`

Comment: no, but using npm install @types/jQuery I didn't had to. Since the cdn packages uses global variable $, type definitions should too..

Comment: I see `declare const $: JQueryStatic` in @types/jquery/misc.d.ts. I guess the problem is with tsconfig.json which has probably different default values than `<TypeScriptCompile>` in csproj….

Comment: @Liero Could you please elaborate on "but using npm install @types/jQuery I didn't had to". I just tried `npm i @types/jQuery ` , the files downloaded are exactly the same.  Have you configured the path mapping ?

Comment: @Liero I find that the default path for aspnet-core project is `wwwroot/lib/@types`, so if you're creating a aspnet-core project and install the dependencies by default, you need change the path to `"jquery": ["wwwroot/lib/@types/jquery"] ,` and `"bootstrap":["wwwroot/lib/@types/bootstrap"]`

Comment: I've solved it by using "typeRoots": [ "wwwroot/lib/@types" ], but I have different issue using this approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536608/how-to-use-libman-instead-of-npm-to-download-typescript-definitions

Answer (score 1):

For those that would rather just type it in themselves: The JSON generated by `libman install @types/jquery -p unpkg`

```
{
    "provider": "unpkg",
    "library": "@types/jquery@3.3.29",
    "destination": "wwwroot/js/lib/@types/jquery"
}
```

(Note: I had an existing `libman.json` file, and this was added to the `"libraries"` array)